# Как создать ссылку, при нажатии на которую открывается фото в большем размере

Tags: php

Здравствуйте не могу решить проблемку. есть кусочек кода который не работает. то что написано внутри тега img echo не работает. первый php запрос создаёт ссылку. при нажатии на изображение оно открываться в большом размере. как еще можно этот  echo написать?

```
<?php echo Helper_HTML::file_anchor(
    Modules_Board_Controllers_Index::PATH_VIEW_NORMAL.$this -> Ad -> ad_foto,
    '<img style="background: url(<?php echo Modules_Board_Controllers_Index::PATH_VIEW_THUMB.$this -> Ad -> ad_foto ?>)">'
) ?>
```

Comment: отредактируйте метку вопроса, добавьте тег фреймворка

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то должно быть так

```
$foto = $Modules_Board_Controllers_Index::PATH_VIEW_NORMAL.$this->Ad->ad_foto;
$thumb = $Modules_Board_Controllers_Index::PATH_VIEW_THUMB.$this->Ad->ad_foto;
echo Helper_HTML::file_anchor(
  $foto,
  sprintf('<img style="background: url(%s)">', $thumb)
);
```

Comment: а что это за фреймверк?

Comment: @dpi Вы у меня спрашиваете? Понятия не имею